Can't use imports with "text!" prefix in my angularjs/webpack application
I'm working on a big and complex AngularJs app, and I'm migrating it from Gulp to Webpack. I'm facing a problem that I couldn't solve, basically I have some imports like
define(['text!./Page.html', 'text!./style.css'], function(template, style) {...

and webpack doesn't return the template as a string. Instead, it returned a module.
HTML page as a Module
I already tried some approaches, like using "text-loader", with resolveLoader alias and creating a custom loader, but it didn't work.
HTML page with text-loader
In summary, I don't want to change my code (removing the "text!" prefix and importing the template and css with "import ... from ..."), because its a big and complex app. What i need is somehow, tell webpack to give me these data, when it find the "text!" prefix, as a string, not a Module.
I prepared a small project, where you can simulate the problem described here:
sample-project
To simulate the problem, just do
npx webpack

This will create the dist folder.
cd dist

http-server

Then, click on the first url on the CMD (127.0...). This will show you the webpack output on the right side. When you update the code, just delete the "dist" folder and then repeat the commands.
The final result should be the html page with the css applied.
I'm stuck with this problem for few weeks now. If somebody could help me I would appreciate a lot. Thanks.
